# How do I get this custom array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I want the first four notifications that are unread `notifications.where(:read => false)[0,4].map`. However, if there are fewer than four notifications that are unread, I want the rest of the four notifications to be filled up by read ones. How do I do this?

(Also, the `.where(:read => false)` doesn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(notifications.where(:read => false).limit(4) + notifications.where(:read => true).limit(4))[0,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
notifications.order(:read).limit(4)
```

Which should give you falses first then trues.